# SQLite and SQLite-Extensions can not perform OneToOne relationsip

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm using [SQLite-Net-Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions). I'm attempting to define a `OneToOne` relationship so that when my `Accounts` model is loaded it will also include the `Campaign` so that I can access the campaign name.

The problem is `Accounts.Campaign` is always `null`. I have data in both tables.

Here's my tables in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaigns` (
    `Id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `Name`  TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
    `Id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CampaignId`    INTEGER,
    `MobileNumber`  TEXT UNIQUE,
    `Password`  TEXT
);
```

Below are my models:

```
namespace SMA.Models
{
    [SQLite.Table("accounts")]
    class Accounts
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Campaigns))]
        public Int32 CampaignId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(11)]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

       [OneToOne("Id")]
       public Campaigns Campaign { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace SMA.Models
{
    [Table("campaigns")]
    class Campaigns
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I run the following code to fetch all of the accounts:

```
var accounts = this.db.Table<SMA.Models.Accounts>().ToList();
```

Also tried ...

```
var accounts = this.db.Query<Account>("SELECT * FROM accounts");
```

And ...

```
var accounts = this.db.Query<Account>("SELECT * FROM accounts JOIN campaigns ON accounts.CampaignID = campaigns.ID");
```

When I inspect `accounts` the account data is there, but `Accounts.Campaign` is `null`. I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [SQLite-Net Extension read methods](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/HEAD/SQLiteNetExtensions/Extensions/ReadOperations.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) instead of plain sqlite.net `Query` or `Table`. For example:

```
var accounts = this.db.GetAllWithChildren<Account>();
```

Also, make sure that you're either setting foreign keys manually or using SQLite-Net Extensions to write relationships to database.

To make SQLite-Net Extensions methods available make sure that you're importing `SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions` namespace:

```
import SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;
```

If they're still not available, make sure that there are no duplicated sqlite.net libraries in your packages.

Comment: `GetAllWithChildren` isn't available. I am setting `this.db` like so ... `this.db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLiteConnectionString(this.dbFileName, true).ConnectionString);`. Do I have to use a SQLite-Net-Extensions connection methods?

Comment: @BugHunterUK SQLite-Net Extensions extends standard sqlite.net connection class, so that connection should work fine. Are you importing `SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions` namespace to bring up the extension methods?

Comment: I was using `SQLite` instead of `SQLite.Net` to create the connection. Works fine now thank you.